# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException being thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I am trying to use a bean generated in another class to be used in the main application

```java
    package com.simon.spring.basics.properties;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class SomeExternalService {

        @Value("${external.service.url}")

        private String url;

        public String returnServiceURL(){
            return url;
        }
    }
```

And the main application is here:

```java
    package com.simon.spring.basics.springin5steps;

    import com.simon.spring.basics.properties.SomeExternalService;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
    @SpringBootApplication
    //@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    @ComponentScan()
    public class SpringIn5StepsPropertiesApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ApplicationContext applicationContext =
                    SpringApplication.run(SpringIn5StepsPropertiesApplication.class, args);
            SomeExternalService service = applicationContext.getBean(SomeExternalService.class);
            System.out.println(service);

    }


}
```

So basically a Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.simon.spring.basics.properties.SomeExternalService' available is being thrown.
What Can I do to fix this error and to avoid the same problems later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `SpringIn5StepsPropertiesApplication` in your package root;

```
package com.simon.spring.basics
```

also remove unnecessary `@ComponentScan()`

---

`@SpringBootApplication` will automatically trigger a component scan under all packages from the location of main class, namely `com.simon.spring.basics`, so your component in `com.simon.spring.basics.properties` can be picked up.

Otherwise it will try to find beans under `com.simon.spring.basics.springin5steps` and fail to find `SomeExternalService`

---

If moving the main class is not an option, then you can add the other package like;

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {com.simon.spring.basics.properties.SomeExternalService.class})
```